Ошибка "InvalidProgramException: Среда выполнения Common Language Runtime обнаружила недопустимую программу" в Pascal ABC
Хочу сделать простой генерированый чат.
uses crt;
    
    var user: array [1..3] of string = ('user1','user2','user3');
    
    begin
    writeln(user[PABCsystem.Random(3).tostring]);
    end.

Консоль выводит это:

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Среда выполнения Common Language Runtime обнаружила недопустимую программу.
в чат user list.Program.$Main()
в чат user list.Program.Main()Программа завершена, нажмите любую клавишу . . .

